# Virtual network - tracert to local vm results in over 255 hops

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, vswitch, virtual-network

Why does my tracert take over a maximum of 255 hops, when both vm's are on the same local network, hosted on my laptop?

I have a laptop which is connected to my home router via wireless lan with Hyper-V enabled.
I have created two virtual switches: external and internal.
I have two virtual machines each connected to both switches and both running on Windows 2012.
Second vm hosts a DC and a DNS Server, both vm's are in this local domain.

When I do a tracert (ip) from one vm to the other, it tells me: over a maximum over 30 hops!??
Something must be wrong, it should not be over 30 hops, cause all the devices and vm's are in the same network. Actually it should be: vm1 -> internalSwitch -> vm2.
How to troubleshoot this. I'm a developer, so I am sorry for asking such stupid questions.

---

--> tracert -h 255 192.168.1.177

> Tracing route to vmsp2013.xdomain.local [192.168.1.177]
>   over a maximum of 255 hops:
>
> 1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  vmsp2013.xdomain.local [192.168.1.177]
>
> Trace complete.

---

**IP Configuration of the network**

Home-Router:        IP 192.168.1.1   - 255.255.255.0

vInternalSwitch: IP **192.168.1.10**  - 255.255.255.0 (=**Default Gateway** for internal network)

vExternalSwitch: IP 192.168.1.74  - 255.255.255.0

---

VM1:
IP 192.168.1.183-
255.255.255.0 - Gateway: 192.168.1.1-
DNS: 192.168.1.1

IP 192.168.1.177-
255.255.255.0 - Gateway: **192.168.1.10** -
DNS: 192.168.1.176

---

VM2 (DC):
IP 192.168.1.176-
255.255.255.0 -
Gateway: **192.168.1.10**-
DNS: 127.0.0.1

IP 192.168.1.182-
255.255.255.0 -
Gateway: 192.168.1.1-
DNS: 192.168.1.1

Answer (score 2):

> Tracing route to vmsp2013.xdomain.local [192.168.1.177] over a maximum
>   of 255 hops:

As our good friend Inigo says "I do not think it means what you think it means."

That is **not** saying that it took over 255 hops. Rather, it's stating that tracert will not report on any more than 255 hops.

In the output, you can clearly see that the host is reachable with one single, measly hop.